# Do not want to load application.yml when testing with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

How can I tell Spring to load only application-test.yml and not application.yml file ?

I have a config class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootConfiguration

public class MongoTestConfig {

    @Autowired
    MongoOperations operations;
...
}
```

And a test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest
@SpringBootTest(classes = MongoTestConfig.class)
public class TagDefinitionRepositoryTest {
...
@Test
....
}
```

I've tried to add :

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:application-test.yml"})
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

To my config class but it doesn't work: Spring still load application.yml

Comment: I don't think you can tell spring to not load application.yml. But You can override the properties which are there in application.yml with `@TestPropertySource`. So that should be enough I believe

Comment: @pvpkiran It's not enough in my case since I get this error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mongo configuration, either uri or host/port/credentials must be specified. In fact in my applicaiton.yml I have a uri specified for mongo and the embedded mongo configured with "@DataMongoTest" uses a host/port/credentials

Comment: `@ActiveProfiles("test")` **must** be declared on the _test class_, not on the `@SpringBootConfiguration` class.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can tell Spring Boot to ignore `application.yml` completely. What you can do though is to override all the non desired properties using test specific property files.

Based on the code snippet you posted, any property in `application-test.yml` will override the equivalent property in `application.yml`.

Spring Boot considers `application-test.yml` specific to the profile "test" (which has a higher priority over the default application.yml). No annotation `@TestPropertySource` is needed.

But if you want to choose another name for your properties file, then you can use `@TestProertySource`, since files indicated in `@TestProperySource` parameters have higher priority over the others.

You might want to have a look at Spring Boot [external configuration rules for resolving properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Answer (score -1):

I've end up using @SpringBootTest instead of @DataMongoTest

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.package.services"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.package.repositories"})
public class MongoTestConfig {

private static final MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() throws IOException {
    MongodExecutable _mongodExe;
    MongodProcess _mongod;

    _mongodExe = starter.prepare(new MongodConfigBuilder()
            .version(Version.Main.V3_2)
            .net(new Net("localhost", 12345, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
            .build());

    _mongod = _mongodExe.start();


    MongoClient _mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 12345);

    return _mongo;

}

@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws IOException{
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient() , "test");
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws IOException {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
}
```

And my test class is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyRepositoryTest {
...
```